# NSURLConnection Timeout frequently a few seconds after the request

Tags: ios, objective-c, timeout, nsurlconnection

I'm having a weird problem in my app. The NSURLConnection goes frequently to the following delegate method (a few seconds after the request before the timeout occurs):

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
  if (DEBUG_ON)
      NSLog(@"No connection");
  UIAlertView *popup = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Error", nil) message:NSLocalizedString(@"TimeoutError", nil) delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
  popup.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleDefault;
  [popup show];
}
```

I'm doing all my connections like this:

```
NSString *dataStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:LOGIN_JSON_TEMPLATE, email, passwd];
NSData *data = [dataStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:LOGIN_WS];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [data length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:data];
if (self.loginConnection == nil)
    self.loginConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
else
    self.loginConnection = [self.loginConnection initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

If i'm right there's a default timeout for the request (60 seconds?). I tried to change it but it didn't change anything.

Any idea why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `setTimeoutInterval` should be maximum something like 60 seconds, or 60*n, where n can be any +ve integer > 0.

Comment: I've done that already and it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request1 = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:1200.0];
```

Instead of

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
```

and you can change timeoutinterval.